# Oracle Bulk Import

Tags: sql, oracle, dbvisualizer

Bulk Import in Oracle

I have created the table emp and I need to import bulk data from a file into emp

For Ex

```
CREATE TABLE emp

( c1 NUMBER,

  c2 VARCHAR2(30)

)
```

File path  : 
`'C:\Documents and Settings\TestUser\My Documents\LearnOracle\reports.csv'`

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the inbuilt tool sql*loader to load data from external flat files into oracle.
 1. create a control file control.ctl

```
  load data
  infile 'reports.csv' 
  into table emp
  fields terminated by ',' optionally
  enclosed by '"'
  c1,c2
```

2. data file is your reports.csv

3.invoke sql*loader: 
 $ sqlldr scott/tiger control=control.ctl
Note: this is the name of the control file that you have made

Comment: You might want to check out this 10 min tutorial. Go through it and you will have a good understanding about the sql*loader tool
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/oracle-sqlldr/

Answer (score 1):

Write a Control file, say `emp.ctl`

```
load data
 options(direct=true)
insert
 into table emp
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
 ( 
    c1 DECIMAL EXTERNAL,
    c2
)
```

Execute [SQL*Loader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm) as below.

```
sqlldr userid=user/pass@db data=reports.csv control=emp.ctl
```

If you always want to refresh the table with your data completely. `TRUNCATE` the table and then load.

`SQL*Loader` is great utility that provide numerous options for performance. Kindly go through the documentation about [DIRECT and CONVENTIONAL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96652/ch09.htm) loading.

There's something called [EXTERNAL tables](http://psoug.org/reference/externaltab.html), that might interest you as well. They use the flat file for the table data.