# csv file import into DB using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, csv

I have requirement, where we have to read the huge csv file and dump data into sql table as it is.
We are using hibernate for current project, any suggestion for importing csv file into db using hibernate with keeping eye on performance too.
is there any tools available for csv to database dumb.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to do that programmatically, [SQLDeveloper](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/) or similar tools can do the job.

Otherwise you can use a simple bulk insert.
Its syntax depends on your DBMS:

- [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241428/oracle-bulk-import)
- [SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server)

For bulk operations ("*...to read the **huge** csv file and dump data...*") you should opt for pure JDBC: any ORM introduces unavoidable overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is ok for transactional operations, but might not be the best tool for bulk loads or ETL process.

I would use some specialized tool like Integration Services.